# Interpolate between two matrices with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two HxW matrices `A` and `B`. I'd like to get an NxHxW matrix `C` such that `C[0]=A`, `C[-1]=B`, and each of the remaining `N-2` slices are linearly interpolated between `A` and `B`. Is there a single numpy function I can do this with, without needing a for loop?

Comment: There's bunch of options in `scipy.interpolate` module.

Comment: No need for interpolate if its just linear interpolation between 2 points (respective for each matrix). Just use `np.linspace` which is equivalent in this case. And it has the nice property of being broadcastable from every element in A to the corresponding element in B. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use linspace if you are looking for linear interpolation between just 2 points.

```
A = np.array([[0,1],
              [2,3]])

B = np.array([[1,  3],
              [-1,-2]])

C = np.linspace(A,B,4)   #<- Change this to H+2, which is H linearly interpolated values between the 2 points
C
```

```
array([[[ 0.        ,  1.        ],     #<-- A matrix is C[0]
        [ 2.        ,  3.        ]],

       [[ 0.33333333,  1.66666667],
        [ 1.        ,  1.33333333]],    #
                                        #<-- Elementwise equally spaced values
       [[ 0.66666667,  2.33333333],     #
        [ 0.        , -0.33333333]],

       [[ 1.        ,  3.        ],     #<-- B matrix is C[-1]
        [-1.        , -2.        ]]])
```